# Relative variance (Vectorised implemantation) in R

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

Say i have a (n x m) matrix in r. Here is a reproducible example.

`values <- matrix(rexp(440, rate=.1), ncol=44)`

I would like to compute the below relative variance of these. Essentially i would like to compute this

[image]

This should return a `(1 x m)` matrix. A single computation in the first column would be something like this.

```
sum((values[10,9] / values[9,9])^2 / length(values[,1]))
```

I tried to loop this as ,

```
  for (i in 2 : length(values)) {
    values_new <- sum((values[i,i-1] / values[i-1,i-1])) ^ 2 / 10
  }
```

I am not sure how to go about with a loop or a vectorized implementation. Appreciate your help.

Comment: The image you linked is blank

Comment: In your for-loop: `length(values)` is 440 in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do:

```
colMeans((values[-1, ] / values[-nrow(values), ]) ^ 2)
```

Matrix manipulations/operations in R are fully vectorized.

The above code will divide all the values (except the first row) by all the values (except the last row), put everything in power of 2 and then calculate the resulting columns mean (notice that because we get a `nrow(values) - 1` rows per column, we can simply calculate the column means).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try a vectorized version per column and use apply to go over all columns. Here is an example:

```
apply(values, 2, function(x){
  z <- x[2:length(x)]
  g <- x[1:(length(x)-1)]
  return(sum((z/g)^2)/(length(x)-1))
})
```

explanation:

`z` is the same as `x` without the first element
`g` is the same as `x` without the last element

`z/g[1]` is the same as `x[2]/x[1]` and so on.. In other words for the first column:

```
sum((values[2:10,1]/values[1:9,1])^2)/(length(values[,1])-1)
```

`apply` goes over the matrix, column by column (since the second argument `MARGIN` was set to `2`) and performs a function. The function performed here is anonymous (defined in place).

Comment: Nice. This is a good example of using the `apply()` function.

Comment: stochastiker be sure to check the answer by @David Arenburg which is faster and more compact.